# SQL Server : Subquery Issue 900

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-server-2016

I am using Sql Server Management Studio 2016, I have a query that returns less than 10 results, problem is I need to order the results by a specific text field, but the order required is not alphabetical. If the possible results were abc, cde, ghf etc, I want to choose cde first and ignore the others, if that is not available then ghf, if non of those then abc. Because this is a subquery I always get the same number of results from the higher level select, but only want the one that meets the first value in the list ignoring all others. Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Question isn't especially clear. You want to order based on a finite set of possible values that you define?

Comment: Can you show your table structure and some code?

Answer (score 1):

One method you can use is a `join`:

```
select top 1 q.*
from (<your query here>) q left join
     (values ('abc', 1), ('def', 2), . . . 
     ) v(val, ordering)
     on q.col = v.val
order by v.ordering;
```

Another method is even simpler . . .

```
select top 1 q.*
from (<your query here>) q
order by charindex('[' + col + ']', '[abc],[def],...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you can use a `case` expression to return a value based on the column you want to assign a custom sort to:

```
select *
from t
order by 
  case col
    when 'cde' then 0
    when 'ghf' then 1
    when 'abc' then 2
  else 3
  end
```